# how to alert javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to study the jquery class, but I have a hard time debugging an object because I can't see the element inside of it

```js
$("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui);
    }
});
```

it returns [object Object].. :( My question is how can I alert the object so that I can see the element?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i recommend you use [FireBug for debugging javascript](http://getfirebug.com/). then you can just do

```
console.log(ui)
```

and it'll log the object in a form you can expand

Comment: @scott How do I do it with Chrome?

Answer (score 12):

Just convert your object to a JSON object using stringfy.

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(yourObjectVariable));
```

simple as pie :)

Answer (score 4):

you can also try Java Script method:

```
 // Alert javascript object in alert box
    function alertObject(obj){      
        for(var key in obj) {
        alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + obj[key]);
        if( typeof obj[key] === 'object' ) {
            alertObject(obj[key]);
        }
        }
    }
```

Here 'obj' is:

```
// your object var
var getObject = {};

// object set with key an val
getObject.swfVersionStr = '10.0';
getObject.xiSwfUrlStr = null;
getObject.flashvarsObj = {};
getObject.parObj = {allowfullscreen: "true",wmode: "window",menu: "false"};
```

Call like this:

```
alertObject(getObject );
```

So, simple.. :)

Comment: thanks singh, this is the best way to show object in alert. there are lot of situations when you dont want to use console.log or is unavailable. Great!

Answer (score 3):

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, null, 4));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox then you can alert object value like below code

```
 alert(object.toSource());   // for you alert(ul.toSource());
```

That above code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your **array or object** to a *JSON object* using `stringify`.

Example:

```
var obj = { "name":"bayiha", "age":30, "city":"Eseka"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

alert(myJSON);
```

[for more info clik here](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)