# Need code to return array coordinates

Tags: javascript, object

newbie question here..
I'm trying to return the LAT LNG values from the array.

I have the following three functions:

```
function City(ridge)
{
    var city=   {
    ABC:"Bethel, AK",
    ABR:"Aberdeen, SD",
    ABX:"Albuquerque, NM"};
    return city[ridge];
}
```

and

```
function BBox(ridge,product)
{
    var yx= {
    NOR:
    {
    ABC:[64.835517,56.735755,-157.448578,-166.284681]
    ,
    ABR:[48.270508,42.631241, -95.331912,-101.483839]
    ,
    ABX:[37.565036,32.726169,-104.179217,-109.457981]}};
    var xy=yx[product][ridge];
    return {x0:xy[2],x1:xy[3],y0:xy[0],y1:xy[1]};
}
```

and

```
function initialize()
{
var ridge =  'ABC';
var product ='NOR';
var getCityInfoFromRidgeName = City(ridge);
var boundries=BBox(ridge,product);
alert(getCityInfoFromRidgeName);
alert(boundries);
}
```

the alert for **City** returns "Bethel, AK" as expected..
but 
the alert for **BBox** returns "objec Object" instead of the LAT LNG information as hoped.

I'm probably in over my head, but how can I return the LAT LNG from the BBox to a var?

Den

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to alert javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580754/how-to-alert-javascript-object)

Comment: he wants to know how to return values from on object into a variable - not how to convert an object into a string to be alerted.

Comment: @Jimmery "but the alert for BBox returns "object Object" instead of the LAT LNG information as hoped." pretty sure it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: @jbabey - read the last line, you know, the line with the question mark on it - "but how can I return the LAT LNG from the BBox to a var?" - he is just using alert to see if he has the right values, but what he actually wants to do is put a value from BBox into a variable.

Comment: @Jimmery he's already doing that: `return {x0:xy[2],x1:xy[3],y0:xy[0],y1:xy[1]};` works fine.

Comment: @jbabey you obviously dont understand his question. i obviously did as he marked my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boundries is an object holding the x and y coords. you can get at the coords with this code:

```
alert(boundries.x0);
alert(boundries.x1);
alert(boundries.y0);
alert(boundries.y1);
```

for future reference, objects in javascript can be created like this:

```
var anObject={property:'value'};
var anotherObject={
    message:'Hello',
    location:'World',
    aNumber:23
};
```

and then parts of an object can be accessed with a dot - like this:

```
anObject.property;
alert(anotherObject.message + ' ' + anotherObject.location);
```

you can learn more about javascript objects here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/