# Giving an object property an array value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I want to make the deck array full of 52 different cards. Whenever I run the code and the card object is alerted it displays as '[object Object]'.

Can someone explain to me why it does this and a solution for this problem?

```
var suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"];
var ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];
var deck = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
        var card = {rank: ranks[j], suit: suits[i]};
        deck.push(card);
        alert(card)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can alert `card.rank` or `card.suit` but not `card`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to alert javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580754/how-to-alert-javascript-object) or [Print content of JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why it does this**

This is perfectly normal. The card object you create doesn't know how to represent itself when you do your `alert()`, simply because there are no `toString()` method implementation.

**Solution for your problem**

Try specifying an anonymous `toString()` function implementation to each card object like this:

```
var suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"];
var ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];
var deck = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {

        var card = {
                       rank: ranks[j], 
                       suit: suits[i],
                       toString : function() { return this.rank + ' ' + this.suit; }
                   };

        deck.push(card);

        //alert(card); // console.log doesn't block code execution
        console.log(card.toString());
    }
}
```

**Note**

You should consider using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` as it is much less annoying and easier to debug in console (hit F12). But be careful with production code running IE9 or lower as their javascript engine will crash when the developper console is not opened.

Comment: I'd either use `alert(card)` (explicitly `alert(card.toString())`) *or* `console.log(card)`, not a mix of them :-)

Comment: For sure, that's why I commented the `alert()` call in the example. ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, I got a but confused with the console.log() and alert(), all working now.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you specify the entire object to alert, and alert does not know which properties are relevant. If you want an expandable view of your object, you can use `console.log(card)`, this will output your object as a tree-view into the browser developer console.

Answer (score 0):

That is how an object is showed, its `toString` method outputs just that, to see its contents use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(card));
```

Comment: Disclaimer: JSON.stringify is great for debugging when you have a fairly new browser. A disappointing number of publically-used browsers don't support it though, so just be sure to have fallbacks, or remove that logging for production code.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qdWAa/)

Replace your alert with this-->alert(JSON.stringify(card))

```
var suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"];
var ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];
var deck = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
        var card = {rank: ranks[j], suit: suits[i]};
        deck.push(card);
       alert(JSON.stringify(card))//CHANGE THIS...
       console.log(JSON.stringify(card))
    }
}
```

[EXPLANATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

JSON.stringify converts JavaScript data structures into JSON text.Json text is nothing but key:value pair of text.It cant get simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your alert to this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(card))
```