# Dynamically retrieving JavaScript property value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to dynamically change the options available to a user. A user will choose either 1 or 2. Once they choose a value, I need to load the options associated with that value. Currently, i have the following:

```
var json = {'1':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Option - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Option - B'}], '2':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Choice - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Choice - B'}]};

var userWants = '1';
alert(json[userWants]);
```

Oddly, the alert window just displays `,`. I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts cannot display `JSON` objects in their *natural* form. Try logging instead

```js
var json = {'1':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Option - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Option - B'}], '2':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Choice - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Choice - B'}]};

var userWants = '1';
console.log(json[userWants]);
```

Also, see [how to alert javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580754/how-to-alert-javascript-object)

Comment: I see the same thing in the console window that I see in my alert window.

Comment: @user70192, what about using the snippet from my answer?

Comment: The snippet works fine. But not in my actual code. I don't understand why.

Comment: @user70192, can you replicate it in a fiddle so I can try and diagnose?

Comment: The problem is that json is actually a string value in my code. So, I'm now using JSON.parse. However, I'm now getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"

Comment: @user70192, it if you can replicate it in a http://jsfiddle.net it will be much easier for us to diagnose

Comment: What exactly is a _pure_ object? `console.log` doesn't display objects in their natural form either. I doubt that anybody would want that.

Answer (score 1):

Alert converts the object to a string using `.toString()`, which doesn't give you nice output:

```
var a = {'value': 'A', 'text': 'Option - A'};
alert(a); // should alert [object Object]
```

You can use `JSON.stringify` to display the object nicely:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(a)); // should alert {"value":"A","text":"Option - A"}
```

Or:

```js
var json = {'1':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Option - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Option - B'}], '2':[{ 'value':'A', 'text':'Choice - A'}, { 'value':'B', 'text':'Choice - B'}]};
var userWants = '1';
alert(JSON.stringify(json[userWants])); // should alert a nicely-formatted list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(json[userWants]);` instead of alert.

You can view the output in console by opening it in Chrome by using the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + J` or by using [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox.